# Sphinx: Document an attribute that is same as a parameter

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I want to document something like this with numpy style docstring.

```
class X(object):
    """ X

    Marble Counter

    Parameters
    ----------
    n_marbles : int
        an indicator of degree of madness

    Attributes
    ----------
    n_marbles : int
        an indicator of degree of madness
    """
    def __init__(n_marbles):
        self.n_marbles = n_marbles
```

The attribute and parameters are the same. Can/should I avoid repeating?

Comment: I will usually put the parameter description in the `__init__` docstring, and add `:special-memers: __init__` to the autodoc, but I don't think that is a standard approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a case like yours, where the input parameter and attribute are the exact same reference, I would only document the attribute. Anyone familiar with Python will immediately know that the parameter is.

For more complex cases, I prefer to document both the class itself and the `__init__` method. The parameter description would go into the docstring of `__init__` in this case.

Since you appear to be using the `autodoc` extension, you would need to add a `:special-members: __init__` option to your `autoclass` directive. If you want to document other special members, you can add them to the parameter list of the option. You can also omit arguments to `:special-members:` entirely to document all magic attributes, but that may include things you don't want, like `__weakref__`.